# Is there a cleaner way to get the corresponding dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x

User enters a pet name and if found in the dictionary, code returns the price of the pet, otherwise asks the user to try a different name. Wondering if this could be done in a cleaner way, with fewer lines of code?

```
pets = {'bird': 3.5, 'cat': 5.0, 'dog': 7.25, 'gerbil': 1.5}

while True:

    req_pet = input("Enter pet name: ")

    if req_pet in pets:
        for (pet, price) in pets.items():
            if pet == req_pet:
                print(price)
                exit(0)
    else:
        print("Pet not found, let's try a different one?")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cut it down a bit by doing:

```
try:
  print(pets[input("Enter pet name: ")])
  exit(0)
except KeyError:
  print("Pet not found, let's try a different one?")
```

This explicitly looks for the input 'key' in the dictionary, and prints the value and exits. If the key doesn't exist it catches the error and prints the message.

If you don't need the `exit` in this way, it can get even shorter using `get` to return a default message instead:

```
print(pets.get(input("Enter pet name: "), "Pet not found, let's try a different one?")
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterating on the dictionary items to find a key defeats the principe of the dict and is very inefficient. Just access it directly:

```
pets = {'bird': 3.5, 'cat': 5.0, 'dog': 7.25, 'gerbil': 1.5}

while True:

    req_pet = input("Enter pet name: ")

    if req_pet in pets:
        print(pets[req_pet])
        exit(0)
    else:
        print("Pet not found, let's try a different one?")
```